# How to add legal disclosure page to a dashboard

Tags: tableau-api

New bee to Tableau and need your help on the below requirement.

I need to **add a legal disclosure as first page to a dashboard** and when user clicks OK only  then we need to go to dashboard.

Dashboard which I created in desktop will be published to the server. I need to share the server link  to the users with the above requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your users only need to see the notice once and click ok, you could create two workbooks. One that you give out the link to which contains your legal notice and a url action pointing to the other dashboard.